# Direct sum/product decomposition of the complexified Lorentz group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics

The usual basis (in the “physics convention”) of $(1, 3)$ is given by six matrices $J^i$, $K^i$ with
\begin{align}
 [J^i, J^j] &= iε^{ijk} J^k
 \\
 [J^i, K^j] &= iε^{ijk} K^k
 \\
 [K^i, K^j] &= -iε^{ijk} J^k
\end{align}
The elements $Λ ∈ \mathrm{SO}(1, 3)^+$ are then given by
\begin{equation}
 Λ = \exp\!\big(-i(\vec{α} ⋅ \vec{J} + \vec{η} ⋅ \vec{K})\big)
\end{equation}

We can go to the complexification $(1, 3)_ℂ$ and choose a new basis $T_{\mathrm{L}/\mathrm{R}}^i = \frac{1}{2} (J^i ± iK^i)$ such that
\begin{align}
 [T_{\mathrm{L}}^i, T_{\mathrm{L}}^j] &= iε^{ijk} T_{\mathrm{L}}^k
 \\
 [T_{\mathrm{R}}^i, T_{\mathrm{R}}^j] &= iε^{ijk} T_{\mathrm{R}}^k
 \\
 [T_{\mathrm{L}}^i, T_{\mathrm{R}}^j] &= 0
\end{align}
This demonstrates that $(1, 3)_ℂ ≅ (2)_ℂ ⊕ (2)_ℂ$.

Now, my question is that since $(1, 3)_ℂ$ decomposes into a direct sum, I would expect the corresponding group to be a direct product:
\begin{equation}
 \exp\!\big((1, 3)_ℂ\big)
 ≅ \exp\!\big((2)_ℂ ⊕ (2)_ℂ\big)
 = \mathrm{SU}(2)_ℂ × \mathrm{SU}(2)_ℂ
\end{equation}
So, in my mind, the elements of this group should be block-diagonal matrices in some form. However, using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, it can be shown that
\begin{equation}
 Λ
 = \exp\!\big(-i(\vec{α} ⋅ \vec{J} + \vec{η} ⋅ \vec{K})\big)
 = \exp\!\big(-i(\vec{α} - i\vec{η}) ⋅ \vec{T}_{\mathrm{L}})\big) \exp\!\big(-i(\vec{α} + i\vec{η}) ⋅ \vec{T}_{\mathrm{R}})\big)
\end{equation}
and while there is a product of two matrices on the right, these matrices are multiplied together instead of being put into a block matrix. How can these two ideas be reconciled?

Comment: $SO(3,1)(C)$ is connected; it is not a direct product but almost: it is isomorphic to the product of two copies of $SL_2(C)$, modulo the diagonally embedded center of order 2.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I’ve removed the reference to $\mathrm{SO}(1, 3)^+_ℂ$ (since it’s not really relevant to the question, anyway).